# how to define require function in typescript

Tags: typescript

this is my ts code:

```
import AddToCartBtn from "./AddToCartBtn";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

declare var document:Document;
var _handler : __React.MouseEventHandler;

ReactDOM.render(<AddToCartBtn clickHandler={_handler}></AddToCartBtn>, document.getElementById("bd"));
```

and compile to js like:

```
define(["require", "exports", "./AddToCartBtn", "react", "react-dom"], function (require, exports, AddToCartBtn_1, React, ReactDOM) {
    var _handler;
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(AddToCartBtn_1.default, {"clickHandler": _handler}), document.getElementById("bd"));
});
```

it is a define function and doesn't work. how do I get a require function?

Comment: can you post your tsconfig or the compiler options you use?

Comment: {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling with --module (or -m) set to amd. You should probably use commonjs.

Answer (score 0):

The define function is expected.  You need require defined in the global scope for it to work though.  Depending on your setup, there are various ways of making this happen.  I have always used the approach listed below:

Typically this could be done by importing require via a script tag in your html (given usage of react, I'm assuming you are targeting the browser).  This assumes your ts file compiles to main.js.  This example is directly from [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
```

Another option is to call require in a different script tag following that:

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["main"]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your `tsconfig.json` settings to this:

```
{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es5", "noImplicitAny": false, "module": "commonjs", "removeComments": false, "sourceMap": true, "jsx": "react" } }
```

Then you will have set the module system to `commonjs` which is the default module system for typescript.